# Pre-buffer videos before it is played in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to buffer multiple videos before it is played. I have created a list of exoplayer instance for each video url, and passed that instances to the playerView which is in different activity. I am not getting any error but the video is not playing at all. I am not sure is this the correct way to achieve the pre-buffering. Below is my method where I am creating an arrayList of player instance.

```
private void setExoPlayer(String videoName, String folderName) {
        SimpleExoPlayer tutorial_player;
        String separator = "/";
        String user_lang = manager.getString("getSelectedLanguage");
        String videoUrl = Constant.appVideosURL + folderName + separator + user_lang + separator + videoName + separator + "hls" + separator + videoName + ".m3u8";
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
                new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);

        TrackSelector trackSelector =
                new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
        DefaultAllocator allocator = new DefaultAllocator(true, C.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
                /*
            parameters to define buffer
            DEFAULT_MIN_BUFFER_MS = 360000
            DEFAULT_MAX_BUFFER_MS = 700000
            Valores default do ExoPlayer2
            DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_MS = 2500
            DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_AFTER_REBUFFER_MS = 5000
        */
        DefaultLoadControl.Builder loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder();
        loadControl.setBufferDurationsMs(360000, 700000, 2500, 5000);
        //Initialize the player
        tutorial_player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(mctx, trackSelector);
        tutorial_player.setVideoScalingMode(C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT);

        // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
                new DefaultDataSourceFactory(mctx, Util.getUserAgent(mctx, "SmartMirror"), bandwidthMeter);

        // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
            MediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(videoUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);
        tutorial_player.prepare(mediaSource);
        tutorial_player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        tutorial_player.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
                String errorString = null;
                if (error.type == ExoPlaybackException.TYPE_RENDERER) {
                    Exception cause = error.getRendererException();
                    if (cause instanceof MediaCodecRenderer.DecoderInitializationException) {
                        // Special case for decoder initialization failures.
                        MediaCodecRenderer.DecoderInitializationException decoderInitializationException =
                                (MediaCodecRenderer.DecoderInitializationException) cause;
                        if (decoderInitializationException.decoderName == null) {
                            if (decoderInitializationException.getCause() instanceof MediaCodecUtil.DecoderQueryException) {
                                errorString = "error querying decoder";
                            } else if (decoderInitializationException.secureDecoderRequired) {
                                errorString = "error_no_secure_decoder";
                            } else {
                                errorString = "error_no_decoder";
                            }
                        } else {
                            errorString = "error_instantiating_decoder";
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        });
        player.add(tutorial_player);

    }
```

Here in this method I am taking only one instance from the arrayList and setting in the player.

```
 public void setVideoPlayerAndMirrorPosition(SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer) {
            playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
            simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

        }
```

I want to know how we can achieve this pre-buffering of multiple videos.